# sails.js - change public folder to be different than .tmp/public

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I reworked sails.js assets flow to fit my needs. I am storing my public assets in /assets/dist.

Is there any easy way to configurate sails app to use my own public folder instead of default "/.tmp/public"?

I know there is option to configure this via /config/local.js, but i want configure this elsewhere(if possible) so it will not be related just to current machine and it will be included in git repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a couple of different answers here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/709

Looks like the easiest way is adding this to your config/local.js file:

```
path: {tmp: ..., public: ...}
```

**Update:**

You can find the default `paths` settings by navigating to: `node_modules/sails/lib/app/configuration/index.js`. If you scroll near the bottom of that file, you will see this:

```
// Built-in path defaults
paths: {
    tmp: path.resolve(appPath, '.tmp')
},
```

If you create a new file in your `config` folder called `paths.js` and add this code to it, you can overwrite/add more default paths to your sails application:

```
module.exports.paths = {
    "tmp" : "assets/dist",
    "public" : "assets/dist"
};
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but i am looking for some other way. as config/local.js is not included in repository and i want change this globaly for all environments.

Comment: You could try editing the core files. From your project root, go to `node_modules/sails/lib/app/configuration/index.js` near there end there is a paths object assigning `tmp` to appPath `.tmp`.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to that file. i was finaly able to solve this problem. i created new config file (config/paths.js) with content `module.exports.paths = { "tmp" : "assets/dist", "public" : "assets/dist" }` and it finaly serves me my assets. can you please update your answer so i can accept it?

Comment: can we add multiple public paths?

Comment: I haven't worked in Sails for over a year now and I am not certain. I Imagine there is a way, @mikermcneil might be able to assist.

Answer (score 3):

The **previous answer clearly doesn't work** on latest versions of `sails.js`. [According this](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3346#issuecomment-159673718) you cannot change paths unless you use the `.sailsrc`.

eg:

```
{
  "paths": {
        "tmp": "dist/assets",
        "public": "dist/assets"
    }
}
```